# Writing a file with a fixed and variable part C

Tags: c, text-files, binaryfiles

I have the following question:
The calendar text file and binary file **should have a name that with a fixed part and a variable part. Use the time function (in time.h) or some other automatic mechanism to make sure that,** when you write the files back out after updating the calendar, you do not overwrite the files you read in but you write a new version of the file that is clearly more recent.
Knowing that I have a program that manages a calendar.
Is it possible to to create a file with a fixed part and a variable part using the `time.h`library ?
Thank you in advance!

Comment: Sure you can... Try to write some code and share it with us.

Comment: Can you please specify how!?
Thank you!

Comment: First you would need to learn C.

Comment: Please visit http://whathaveyoutried.com/ to find out how to make your question better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question is vague, so the answer could only be similar.

From your specification, I guess you need a filename, f.e. "calendar-YYYYMMDDhhmmss.bin" and "calendar-YYYYMMDDhhmmss.txt"

When you "man time.h", you can see, that the time-"library" provides all these data. At the bottom of the man-page you see some related functions like "time()" and "strftime()", which help you to get a timestamp and to format a time to your needs.

If you "http://www.whathaveyoutried.com" and are stuck again, please update your question, and we will help you further.

**EDITH** (to the comment):

That depends on whether you should have a lot of files with each containing one "calendar" and the most recent dateded file is the actual calendar and the olde ones are backups; or you have one calendar-file with a new section for each "calendar", then you have to define (for yourself) how to organise these actual and historical sections.

as a matter of fact i would prefere the first solution, so each time you update your calendar, you call "fopen(path_filename_timestamp_txt, "w");". In the second case you would call "fopen(path_filename_txt, "a");" and "fwrite(timestamp);" your section-header;

Please show us, what you have done so far! (as short as possible, according to http://sscce.org/)

Comment: My question is the following: How can I timestamp a text file using the time.h library? Am I suopposed to just write the time at the very beggining of the file or is there a special way to do the timestamping? Thank You in advance